# Django - Include a media into a specific admin page

Tags: python, django, media, django-modeladmin

If I have this kind of modelAdmin:

**admin.py**

```
#...
class ScribPartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  class Media:
    css = {
      'all': ('css/mymarkup.css',)
    }

admin.site.register(ScribPart, ScribPartAdmin)
#...
```

`mymarkup.css` is actually included in all the pages concerning the object `ScribPart`.

How can I specify in which `change_form`, `change_list`, `add_form`, ... template I need this css ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you would need to override the template files for these views. You can inherit from the default template files, and just add your custom CSS in the `extrahead` block.

Comment: You mean overriding `my_project/template/admin/my_app/scribpart/change_form.html` would be the only way ?

Comment: For the change form template, you can use the code you included in your question. But for all other views, I believe you would need to override the template.

Comment: @Glide, why not?  Templates is a right place to work with CSS and overriding them [is easy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).  Anyway, [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions) says that media definitions of `ModelAdmin` used in all add/change admin views.

Comment: Ok so I'm wondering in which case would we need the ModelAdmin media definition :) Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a `.js` file wich load a specific css file for each page.